# Translation of Fock's original paper?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, second-quantization, specific-reference

Has the original paper on the Fock space [1] ever been translated to English? I'm not looking for things like Cook's paper [2], what I want is a faithful traslation from German (if it exists).

[1] V. Fock, *Konfigurationsraum und zweite Quantelung*, Z. Phys. **75**, 622-647 (1932). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01344458

[2] J. M. Cook, *The mathematics of second quantization*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **74** 222-245, (1953).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this famous article by V.A. Fock has been translated from German to English, and quite [recently](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0415300029). It is published in English in:

> Faddeev, L.D. et al. - „**V.A. Fock. Selected works: quantum mechanics
> and quantum field theory**”, CRC (Chapman & Hall), 2004, *page 191*.

```
Library of Congress Cataloging-in-Publication Data
Fock, V. A. (Vladimir Aleksandrovich), 1898-1974
[Selections. English. 2004]
V.A. Fock--selected works : quantum mechanics and quantum field theory / by L.D.
Faddeev, L.A. Khalfin, I.V. Komarov.
p. cm.
Includes bibliographical references and index.
ISBN 0-415-30002-9 (alk. paper)
1. Quantum theory. 2. Quantum field theory. I. Title: Quantum mechanics and quantum
field theory. II. Faddeev, L. D. III. Khalfin, L. A. IV. Komarov, I. V. V. Title.
```